# How can I fix multiple URLs pointing to a single page using ASP/IIS

Tags: duplicate-content, iis, clean-urls, asp

I have millions of reports in our ASP website and have changed my URL structure lots of times to make the URLs more user-friendly as per SEO guidelines.

Currently I am facing duplicate content problems as my URLs are different but they are targeting the same report page. For example, these three URLs all redirect to same report and are live on my website:

```
example.com/market-research-reports/alternative-renewable-market-research-report/analysing-outlook-wind-power-india.html`

example.com/alternative-renewable-market-research-reports/analysing-outlook-wind-power-india.html

example.com/alternative-renewable-market-research-reports-554645/analysing-outlook-wind-power-india.html
```

Can anyone suggest how to rectify all these duplicate links, and how I can manage to remove the old URLs?

Note that this site uses ASP with IIS.